# What is a verb that means 'to make a small amount of money last for several days'?

Tags: single-word-requests

It happens to me every month particularly the last week. I have a little amount of money. I have to manage the expenses till I get my salary. So I make such a small amount of money last for several days.

It happens not only in the matter of money but grocery items also. Is there any word to imply the activity "**making something little last for several days"**?

I need single word (a verb) for the verbal phrase 'make a small amount of money last for several days'.

Comment: A little stash to tide you over?

Comment: An old one 'make do and mend' or just 'make do'. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-do

Comment: You ask for 'a word'. Do you want a noun, a verb or an adjective? How would you use the word in a sentence? Please give an example.

Comment: *Making ends meet*, *stretching your dollar*, *tightening your belt*, *rationing*, etc etc.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK.   I have to make small amount of money last for several days. I need single word for the verbal phrase 'make small amount of money last for several days'.

Comment: Okay - As you want a single word,  I suggest 'economize'. See my answer.

Comment: "Stretch" is the first term that comes to mind.

Comment: 'Conserve' should fit too

Comment: Extending/prolonging its life/use.

Answer (score 68):

One useful word for "making something little last for several days" is *eke,* which is always used with an object and *out*.

> [with object] (**eke something out**)
>   1 Make an amount or supply of something last longer by using or consuming it frugally:
>   *the remains of yesterday’s stew could be eked out to make another meal*
>
> 1.1 Manage to make a living with difficulty:
>   *many traders barely eked out a living*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eke)]

You are ***eking out*** your salary and food.

Comment: Yes. The Old English word *eke* - to lengthen, or stretch out, maybe connected to the noun *eke* (Norse *auke*) meaning 'an increase', or 'piece added on'. It is interesting to me since my grandmother's maiden surname was *Eke*, and there were several families of them in the Norfolk villages round about her. In that case, however, I think the connection is to *oak*. I think I'm right in saying that it is the current Danish for *oak*.

Comment: I had an argument once with someone who insisted that it's an abbreviation of *economise*.

Comment: @WS2 Not quite; the Danish for ‘oak’ is _eg_ (plural _ege_); the Swedish word is _ek_, but its plural is _ekar_. So both are close, but not quite the same (and both they and English _oak_ are of course etymologically unrelated). More interestingly, though, the same root/word also yielded the pre-Norse _auk_, which in time has yielded Danish/Norwegian/Icelandic/Faeroese _og_, Swedish _och_, meaning simply ‘and’. This is an almost identical development to the now archaic English word _eke_, meaning ‘also’: increase → addition → additionally → also → and.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Any thoughts then about an English surname *Eke*? You mention that Danish *eg* and English *oak* are etymologically unrelated - but OED says under *oak*: *Etymology:  Cognate with Old Frisian ēk , Middle Dutch eike , eke  (Dutch eik , †eek ), Old Saxon ēc  (Middle Low German eik , ēk , eike , ēke ), Old High German eih , eihha  (Middle High German eich , eiche , German Eiche ), Old Icelandic eik , Old Swedish ek  (Swedish ek ), Danish eg ;* (continued)

Comment: B.Fwd: *further etymology uncertain: probably related to Hellenistic Greek αἰγίλωψ  kind of oak tree (see aegilops n.), κράταιγος thorn, and perhaps also to classical Latin aesculus mountain oak.*

Comment: @WS2 The surname might well be related to the tree. The Scandiwegian and English words for _oak_ are obviously related to each other; but they are not related to the root _eke_ meaning ‘addition/increase’. Their Germanic preforms are _*aik-_ and _*auk-_, respectively.

Comment: Note that originally, "eke out" meant something like "supplement", i.e. the reason ekeing out the soup made it last longer was that you added something to it (albeit that "something" may have just been water). You will sometimes meet pedants who insist the word must continue to be used that way, i.e. using it to mean "struggling to stretch out" is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 57):

You want the idiomatic use of the verb *[stretch](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20gustatory&oq=define%20gustatory&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3430j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20stretch)* meaning "last or cause to last longer than expected."  From *[Steven Smale: The Mathematician Who Broke the Dimension Barrier](https://books.google.com/books?id=C1cLnAm7gcwC&pg=PA20&dq=%22stretch%20the%20money%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwADgKahUKEwjT69nQgNbIAhUCdT4KHetJCdk#v=onepage&q=%22stretch%20the%20money%22&f=false)* by Steve Batterso:

> Determined to **stretch** the money as far as possible, he lived
>   frugally in a tiny, windowless Greenwich Village apartment.

Comment: As a New Yorker that example does make me laugh. Even a tiny, windowless apartment is not going to support a frugal lifestyle if it's in Greenwich Village. A typical studio there is going to be tiny (though it'll have at least one window if it's legal) and go for about $2,500/mo. An illegal one like that, if you can find it, might get as low as $1,000/mo., maybe.

Comment: @KRyan This was in the 1950s.

Comment: oh, no doubt, I was just amused at how times have changed

Comment: How do you 'stretch' laundries and groceries? Stretch is good for 'money' I think.

Comment: The google finds plenty of instances for "stretch the groceries."  I think you can stretch any scarce resource.  That probably leaves *laundries* out.

Comment: Laundries are in; you're just unfamiliar with [The Chair](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17467/where-to-put-used-but-usable-clothes-a-k-a-alternative-to-the-chair) ;)

Answer (score 33):

**pinch pennies**

> : to [**stint**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stint) on or be frugal or economical with expenditures;
>   economize.

[Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pinch--pennies)

Also, **scrimp or skimp (on)**

> : (*used without object*): to be sparing or frugal; economize (often
>   followed by on):  They scrimped and saved for everything they have. He
>   spends most of his money on clothes, and scrimps on food.
>
> : (*used with object*): to be sparing or restrictive of
>   or in; limit severely:  to scrimp food.

[Random-House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrimp)

Comment: +1 for _scrimp_, which was the first thing that popped in to my mind.

Comment: frugal was what came to mind for me

Comment: +1 for _scrimp_. I think that's the word that sounds the most idiomatic, as in the common expression _scrimp and save_.

Answer (score 17):

Two that come to mind for me are *conserve* and *scrimp*.  As the OP asks for a single word verb, I think *conserve* is probably a more well known verb, but *scrimp* may be the more closely matching one.

> **scrimp**—verb—be thrifty or parsimonious; economize. ([OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrimp))

For the record, *parsimonious* means

> **parsimonious**—adjective—unwilling to spend money or use resources; *stingy* or *frugal*. ([Google](https://www.google.it/search?q=be%20thrifty%20or%20parsimonious%3B%20economize&oq=be%20thrifty%20or%20parsimonious%3B%20economize&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=parsimonious%20definition))

Here is an example of usage of [**scrimp and save**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrimp) from Collins English Dictionary:

> *I'm glad the Italians didn't scrimp and save and move away, like the Whatchamacallits," said Anastasia, after two mouthfuls of spaghetti*.
>   <sub>Lowry, Lois ANASTASIA KRUPNIK (3-IN-1)</sub>

Comment: Scrimp is good -- and it's a verb. EDIT just saw that Elian already mentioned that before you..

Comment: Can you supply the source for your definitions, please?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK yep -- i didn't see it because their first word was "pinch pennies"  as for the definitions, those are straight from google search results front page

Answer (score 10):

[***Subsist***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subsist) is the word you are looking for as it means:

> Maintain or support oneself, especially at a minimal level: ‘he
>   subsisted on welfare and casual labour’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

You can also use [***get by***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_by):

> To subsist; to succeed, survive, or manage, at least at a minimal
>   level. Do you think they can get by on only one salary?

[Wiktionary]

Or [*Tighten one's belt*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tighten_one%27s_belt):

> To be more frugal. To make difficult economic savings due to a
>   lowering of expected income.

[Wiktionary]

Answer (score 8):

**[economize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/economize)**

ɪˈkɒnəmʌɪz
verb

spend less; reduce one's expenses. 
"I have to economize where I can"

synonyms:   save (money), cut expenditure, cut costs;

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/economize)

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but here are some idioms for **being frugal** that haven't been suggested yet:

1. [**stretch a dollar**](http://everyday-mom.com/2011/09/05/50-ways-to-stretch-a-dollar/)
2. **stretch your money** or **make your money stretch**

> Fig. to economize so that one's money lasts longer. *We have to stretch
>   our money in order to be able to buy groceries at the end of the
>   month.*

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stretch+money)

3. **make (both) ends meet**

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+ends+meet)

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one has yet to list the verb "budget"

> [to make and follow a plan for spending your money](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/budget)
>   -Merriam Webster

Comment: but the plan for spending your money isn't necessarily one that consists in 'small amounts'.

Comment: yes that is technically true, however, if one needs a plan in the first place, it seems to indicate that one cannot afford to spend indiscriminately, so I feel like _budget_ has some connotation of frugality in American english.

Answer (score 0):

Being **frugal**

> adjective |
>   sparing or economical as regards money or food.
>   "I'm a bit too frugal to splash out on designer clothes"

Or **scrimping**

> verb |
>   be thrifty or parsimonious; economize.
>   "I have scrimped and saved to give you a good education"

Otherwise, **thrifty**

> adjective |
>   using money and other resources carefully and not wastefully.
>   "he had been brought up to be thrifty and careful"

Comment: *scrimp* (*scrimping* which is the gerund) has been suggested three times already by: [John](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281903/44619); [user 8675...](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281854/44619) and [Elian](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/281836/44619). Please check what others have suggested before posting.

Comment: Neither *frugal* nor *thrifty* are verbs, which the OP has specifically asked for.

Answer (score -7):

To me, *one of the options* is

> to go/walk the extra mile

It could be, as you said, in the context of feeling short of *money, grocery, laundry* or the like.

Though the idiom is used to put efforts to *earn* money, idiom is **also** used to say extra efforts to achieve something. And **here**, you want to achieve the target of 'adjusting everything with whatsoever little money you have' until the month ends.

[**go the extra mile**:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-the-extra-mile) to make a special extra effort in order to achieve something

**Example follows:**

> *We are prepared to go the extra mile to establish peace.*

I don't see *any effort* in making money!

If I construct a sentence, it'd be like...

> It is my regular problem. If the month is ending, I'll have to go/walk an extra mile to meet my expenses, shortage of groceries etc.

Comment: This doesn’t really fit very well here; the meaning of _go the extra mile_ is more accurately that given in one of the other entries on the page you link to: “to try harder to please someone or to get the task done correctly; to do more than one is required to do to reach a goal”. It’s similar to _go above and beyond the call of duty_. You don’t go any extra miles to make your money last longer at the end of the month.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I agree. In a way this is the opposite of what is being asked for. The OP doesn't work harder to make more money. Instead they merely don't spend so much.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet while the idiom is used to earn 'extra money' but it is not *always*. Answer updated.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK extra working is okay but for *money* is not always the case. Answer updated